# Is it possible to force the use of "using" for disposable classes?

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable, using

I need to force the use of "using" to dispose a new instance of a class.

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
   ...
}

using(MyClass obj = new MyClass()) // Force to use "using"
{
}
```

Comment: Why *must* a user of your class dispose of it? Normally you would strongly recommend that they dispose it, to release resources earlier. What's special about your case?

Comment: If you could do that, the resource could only be used in method scope. It would certainly make things easier, but it would also limit the usage significantly.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen: Sometimes limitations can free you to worry about more important things.

Comment: @Zanoni: @Dan Bryant's continuation passing style approach is quite interesting, and is a potentially reasonable way to enforce that resource release happens - at the price of being more confusing. If you need a strong gaurantee of disposal, his solution may work for you.

Comment: @Tragedian, one use case is for a Impersonation class that can impersonate other users. You want to make sure when the instance not used, impersonation will be reverted back and as soon as possible.

Comment: @Zanoni did you find any solution? if not, then I plan to start a bounty.

Comment: @denfromufa all available options are already listed here, so not sure what do you want to achieve with bounty.

Comment: @Evk not satisfied with any option

Comment: @denfromufa In what dark, deeply flawed alternate universe is [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) ***not*** a credible, authoritativesource?

Comment: @Plutonix Eric Lippert is now Hack-er :) but seriously see my comments to his answer

Answer (score 50):

The fact that you *need* to ensure that the object is disposed indicates a design flaw. It's fine if disposing is the *polite* or *efficient* thing to do, but it should not be *semantically necessary*.

There is no way to enforce that an object is disposed of via the `using` statement. However, what you can do is maintain a flag in the object that indicates whether the object was disposed or not, and then write a finalizer that checks that flag. If the finalizer detects that the object wasn't disposed, then you can have the finalizer, say, terminate the process via failfast.  That is, so severely punish the user who neglected to dispose the object that they are forced to either fix their bug or stop using your object.

That doesn't strike me as nice, good, or polite, but you're the only one who knows what the terrible, terrible consequences are of failing to dispose the object. Whether applying a punishment to people who fail to follow your crazy rules is better than living with the consequences of them failing to follow the rules is for you to decide.

Comment: @Eric: It's a funny coincidence, but I posted a similar question to your blog about this topic earlier today. One comment I would make is that disposal becomes semantically necessary when dealing with very limited resources whose consumption can adversly affect an entire process. It would be helpful if the compiler could enforce (or at least warn) when certain disposable resources are not deterministically released - for this purpose I suggested an attribute (RequiresRAIISemantics, or the like) that could be tagged on types implementing IDisposable.

Comment: I find this comment curious, since in most cases destructors/finalizers will only run if code is buggy, and elsewhere you seem to think that it's better for buggy code to fail outright than to mask the bugs and limp along.  Except in the case of shared immutable objects (e.g. a `Bitmap`) which are reasonably abandonment-safe if cached via `WeakReference`, I can't see much excuse for failing to `Dispose` everything (though I find the difficulty of calling `Dispose` on an object whose constructor throws an exception to be very irksome).

Comment: Reading this answer again after years makes me thinking that forcing the disposal of a resource is bad design choice when the resource is some kind of storage. Despite this, using statement is often used when dealing with locks, offering a a clean syntax to operate on resources withing the context of a lock. Forcing the acquisition/release of a lock in a scoped block is again a design choice, but I don't think it can be considered bad in general. In these cases, there's no way to enforce the `using` statement and one has to rely on api design expedients.

Comment: pythonnet does not agree with you @Eric Lipper. Have a look at `using (Py.GIL())` use case. Hence downvoted this answer.

Comment: @denfromufa: I find that use case somewhat bizarre; the proper usage of a global lock is to give it to the **lock** statement, not the **using** statement.

Comment: @EricLippert sorry for typo in your name. `lock` is useful for managed objects, but my understanding is that for unmanaged `Py.GIL()` and unmanaged Python thread(s) this is not going to fly: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/src/runtime/pythonengine.cs#L444

Comment: I believe it's a *very good desing* to enforce the RAII semantics

Comment: @franckspike: Then C++ is the language for you!

Comment: "The fact that you need to ensure that the object is disposed indicates a design flaw" is a misleading statement.  I have an instance using the SMTPClient where it is remaining open 10 minutes after usage and causing issues.  There is no way to close the connection, so the only way to force it closed is to dispose of it.

Answer (score 23):

It's ugly, but you could do something like this:

```
    public sealed class DisposableClass : IDisposable
    {
        private DisposableClass()
        {

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            //Dispose...
        }

        public static void DoSomething(Action<DisposableClass> doSomething)
        {
            using (var disposable = new DisposableClass())
            {
                doSomething(disposable);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a very interesting use of continuation passing style (CPS), but I don't know if it could really be extensible to the general case of acquiring and releasing resources.

Comment: This isn't ugly, rename `DoSomething()` to `DoWithDisposableClass()` and move it to a factory.

Comment: what if multiple unknown methods can stand for `doSomething`?

Answer (score 18):

You can write your own warning/error with the use of the Roslyn framework. Your `DiagnosticAnalyzer` would check all constructor calls to see if your class is being constructed or not and if you are within a `using` statement or not.

The reported diagnostic can be set to Error severity, and can be marked as non-configurable, meaning that nobody can downgrade it to warning or info.

Also, if you are developing a Nuget library you might want to ship your analyzer as a development dependency and add it as an analyzer nuget package. This would result in all of your users being forced to dispose your given class. This packaging is referred to as ["code-aware library"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt297717.aspx).

Note that in theory this could be done by a third party analyzer library too (such as FxCop), but there are many `IDisposable` implementations that do not strictly need to be disposed, such as `MemoryStream`, whose `Dispose` doesn't do a whole lot, so these rules either have some white-listing mechanisms or report false positives.

Comment: Someone did this for us: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/IDisposableAnalyzers

Answer (score 5):

I wonder if [FXCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) could enforce that rule?

Comment: Yes, there is the DisposeObjectsBeforeLosingScope rule. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/22/what-s-new-in-code-analysis-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The using statement is a shorthand that the compiler converts from:

```
(using DisposableObject d = new DisposableObject()){}
```

into:

```
DisposableObject d = new DisposableObject()
try
{

}
finally
{
    if(d != null) d.Dispose();
}
```

so you are more or less asking if it is possible to enforce writing a try/finally block that calls Dispose for an object.

Comment: *Technically*, it would be `((IDisposable)d).Dispose();` ;)

Comment: There actually *is* a difference between them.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx for discussion of implicit vs explicit interface implementation, which includes examples where casting to the interface matters.

Comment: @Brian, thanks for the link. so it's (IDisposable)d because if 
Dispose() is explicitly implemented it may be hidden from d unless cast to the interface.

Comment: And the code might still compile, since there may be an implicit implementation of Dispose, too.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that.  You can't even force them to call dispose.  The best you can do is add a finalizer.  Just keep in mind that the finalizer will get called when the object is disposed and that is up to the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible.  Now what you can do is call the dispose method in the finalizer of the class (and then you can suppress the use of it if they do actually call the dispose method).  That way it will fire if not done explicitly in code.

This link will show you how to implement the finalizer / dispose pattern:

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33167

Answer (score 0):

If you want force to use using on this class, your code to support this class you might code in other class and hide MyClass for normal use.

Comment: This wouldn't work because your "wrapper" class would have to implement IDisposable to allow you to dispose of the original class and you're back at square one, using a finalizer.

Comment: No, the wrapper class may not implement IDisposable is not metter, he control Disposing of MyClass. Yes the wrapper dispose is to dispose her children element (eg. MyClass), but he can dispose MyClass after he end works, and Wrapper class can live along time ago this operation.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), which is a technique that ensures that the acquired resources will be properly disposed.

What I mean is that if you can't force the `Dispose` method to be called (through `using` or directly), you can put its content inside another method that will be called, such as the destructor.

It is a common pattern to implement `IDisposable` as below:

```
// Implement IDisposable.
// Do not make this method virtual.
// A derived class should not be able to override this method.
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    // This object will be cleaned up by the Dispose method.
    // Therefore, you should call GC.SupressFinalize to
    // take this object off the finalization queue 
    // and prevent finalization code for this object
    // from executing a second time.
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

// Dispose(bool disposing) executes in two distinct scenarios.
// If disposing equals true, the method has been called directly
// or indirectly by a user's code. Managed and unmanaged resources
// can be disposed.
// If disposing equals false, the method has been called by the 
// runtime from inside the finalizer and you should not reference 
// other objects. Only unmanaged resources can be disposed.
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // Check to see if Dispose has already been called.
    if(!this.disposed)
    {
        // If disposing equals true, dispose all managed 
        // and unmanaged resources.
        if(disposing)
        {
            // Dispose managed resources.
            component.Dispose();
        }

        // Call the appropriate methods to clean up 
        // unmanaged resources here.
        // If disposing is false, 
        // only the following code is executed.

        // TODO: write code
    }
    disposed = true;         
}

// Use C# destructor syntax for finalization code.
// This destructor will run only if the Dispose method 
// does not get called.
// It gives your base class the opportunity to finalize.
// Do not provide destructors in types derived from this class.
~ClassName()
{
    // Do not re-create Dispose clean-up code here.
    // Calling Dispose(false) is optimal in terms of
    // readability and maintainability.
    Dispose(false);
}
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the disposal of resources withing a scope it's possible, but IDisposable is not really needed. With the following code:

```
public class ResourceHandle
{
    public delegate void ResourceProvider(Resource resource);

    private string _parms;

    public ResourceHandle(string parms)
    {
        _parms = parms;
    }

    public void UseResource(ResourceProvider useResource)
    {
        Resource resource = new Resource(_parms);
        useResource(resource);
        resource.Close();
    }
}


public class Resource
{
    private string _parms;

    internal Resource(string parms)
    {
        // Initialize resource
    }

    internal void Close()
    {
        // Do cleaning
    }

    // Public methods of resource
}
```

You can use the Resource ONLY in this way:

```
public void foo()
{
    ResourceHandle resourceHandle = new ResourceHandle("parms");

    resourceHandle.UseResource(delegate(Resource resource)
        {
            // use resource
        });
}
```

As you can see IDisposable is not really needed here.