# How to hide object pooling?

Tags: c#, .net, object-pooling

For context, I am creating a networking library and have internally implemented object pooling - instances of `byte[]` get reused in order to avoid creating constant garbage.

For users of my library, I have exposed a public `ref struct Packet` which allows the user to perform write operations to the pooled `byte[]`. Here is the code:

```
public ref struct Packet
{
    private readonly byte[] _buffer;

    public Packet()
    {
        // Here we take a byte-array from the pool.
        _buffer = Pool.Get();
    }

    // Some write methods here...

    public void Return()
    {
        // Here byte-array returns to the pool so it can be reused later.
        Pool.Return(_buffer);
    }
}
```

While all of this is great and it works, there are some problems that I have with this approach:

1. I am leaking implementation details: user shouldn't really know or care how packets get their `byte[]`, they only want to get the packet, write some data to it and send it.
2. I am forcing my users to call `Return` method when they are done using the packet.
3. If user forgets to call `Return`, `byte[]` will not get returned and leak occurs.

To somewhat remedy said problems, here is what I tried. Whenever user sends the packet, that send method will call `Return` method for the user.

```
public class Client
{
    public void Send(Packet packet)
    {
        // Performs socket operations here...

        // Returns byte-array to the pool so users don't have to.
        packet.Return();
    }
}
```

While this works most of the time, what if user creates a packet, but does not send it? Again, leak will occur. There seems to be no way to actually hide that library is internally using object pooling and there must exist public `Return` method so user can manually return `byte[]` in case they don't actually send the packet.

So, what I want to achieve is:

1. User doesn't even have access to `Return` method, it is completely hidden from the user.
2. `byte[]` instances get reused (pooled) and are always returned to the pool, even if user does not send the packet or does anything with it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it an option to make the `Packet` implement the `IDisposable` interface?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yeah, however it doesn't really solve anything as now user is forced to use `using` instead of calling `Return`; we simply moved the problem. Also, leaks can still occur as there is no way to force `using` construct (if there was a way to force it, this would certainly be the solution).

Comment: Yep, implementing the `IDisposable` just provides a stronger incentive to dispose the resource, it doesn't enforce it.

Comment: What leaks? Are you talking about memory leaks? I haven't really used `ObjectPool` before but my understanding is that if `Return()` is not called, the byte array will simply be garbage-collected. Is _that_ what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Yes, I am trying to create a high performance library (used in scenarios where creating frequent garbage can lead to problems), so I want to avoid triggering garbage collector as much as possible.

Comment: i believe you have to decide to accept the risk (more control by the end user - point number 2 and 3) or make it easier for people to not use it the way you dont want them to (more control by you - your first point). expanding upon theodor's comment you could also, force a `Return` to happen inside [`Object.Finalizer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.finalize?view=net-6.0). should the end user forget to even dereference it and kept them around forever, i doubt its your problem.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Is it possible to force the use of "using" for disposable classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675504/is-it-possible-to-force-the-use-of-using-for-disposable-classes)

Comment: @FICHEKK How a pool of `byte[]` variables will help you in avoiding "triggering garbage collector as much as possible"? I assume the you are just recycling a reference variable, but not its content which will change for every packet, so will need garbage collection more or less often.

Comment: @GianPaolo Once bytes of `byte[]` have been sent over the socket, that `byte[]` instance can be returned to the pool and later be used by the next `Packet`, there is no need to allocate new `byte[]` for each `Packet`.

Comment: @FICHEKK you mean that you zero somehow the same byte[] and then give it to the following Packet that need it? Yes, It makes sense if garbage collection is something you have to limit it as much as possible

Comment: @GianPaolo Actually, you don't even need to zero the bytes of `byte[]`, next `Packet` will simply overwrite old bytes.

Comment: I think this is a job for `IDisposable` just as everyone should know that (e.g.) a  `DbConnection` should be disposed when finished using it, the same would apply to your Packet class. Note: disposing a db onnection does not close the underlying connection, it just return it to the connection pool; sounds the same as your scenario

Answer (score -1):

I would consider implementing IDisposable. Nevertheless, it could be beneficial to only get from the Pool in case a Send request is invoked:

```
public void Send(Action<Packet> modifyPacket)
{
    // Performs socket operations here...
    var packet = new Packet();
    try
    {
        modifyPacket(packet);        
        // send...
    }
    finally
    {
        packet.Return();
    }
}
```

Thus the payload would be out of the Pool for the shortest amount of time. As I do not know the methods on Packet I do not know in how far you want to hide it.  But I hope you get the idea.

Comment: While this is not exactly the solution I am looking for (I actually think the solution I need might not even be possible with today's C#), I appreciate the idea and effort behind it, so +1.